# django docker-compose --> memcached not working

Tags: django, docker, django-rest-framework, memcached, docker-compose

I'm trying to setup django (rest framework) with memcached using docker-compose.

To enable caching with the rest framework, I'm using [rest_framework_extensions](https://chibisov.github.io/drf-extensions/docs/).

**`docker-compose.yml`**

```
django:
  image: python3
  links:
    - database
    - memcached

memcached:
  image: memcached
  ports:
    - "11211:11211"
```

**`settings.py`**

```
CACHES = {
    'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
    'LOCATION': 'memcached:11211'
}
```

**`viewsets.py`**

```
from rest_framework_extensions.cache.mixins import CacheResponseMixin


class JobPublicViewSet(CacheResponseMixin, viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    pass
```

**Here's my problem:**

With the above sketched configuration and setup, **nothing is cached**.

However, if I remove the `CACHES` entry from the setting, caching is working just fine. Somewhere there seems to be a default setting for local memory cache.

**Can you see why my app doesn't pick up memcached for caching?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The oficial docker image has not set a memory size by default,
you need use a entrypoint on docker compose

```
memcached:
   image: memcached
   ports:
     - "11211:11211"
   entrypoint:
    - memcached
    - -m 64
```